# Having troubles understanding equality

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am currently trying to understand the proof of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+1)}\rightarrow 1$.

I'm having problems understanding the following equality of said proof:
\begin{equation} \left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}\right)+~...~+\left(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)=1-\frac{1}{1+n}\end{equation}
How do I get from the left side to $1-\frac{1}{1+n}$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $-\frac12+\frac12=0$, $-\frac13+\frac13=0$, etc.

Comment: Because $-1/2+1/2=0$, $-1/3+1/3=0$ and so on.

Comment: Write it down for small $n$, e.g. $n=5$. Can you see it now?

Comment: This kind of series is called a [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

Comment: I get it now, thanks. Everything besides the 1 and the $-\frac{1}{n+1}$ in $\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$ cancels out.